# NSPredicate: how to treat strings as numbers?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I am building a compound NSPredicate to make a fetch request, using core data on sqlite, within iOS app. Everything already works fine, but I am not being able to include the last condition. The reason is quite simple: I need to check if the value, stored as a string, is within certain float bounds. The problem is that the conditions are checked on alphabetical order basis, and not according its float value. Here it is the code:

```
NSString * conditionToBeAdded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" && (%@ >= \"""%@\""")  && (%@ <= \"""%@\""")", propertyName, myMinFloat, propertyName, myMaxFloat];
stringForPredicate = [stringForPredicate stringByAppendingString:conditionToBeAdded];  
NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringForPredicate];
```

Does anybody know how to build an NSPredicate object able to check string values as numbers, to be used within a coredata request?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of objects are you filtering? Would it be possible to go the other way around and create a readonly property on your object that converts the string to a NSNumber? This way you'd have total control over the cases, where the stored strings do not comprise a valid number.

Comment: It's the Model of the app, which holds all the data. These objects have many properties, (name, address, price etc.) all of which NSString. By now I solved by performing the fetch without this condition and filtering the array, but it is a little bit slower. I tried your solution, it won't work because it doesn't find the property in the model entity definition, it is a good point but I would need to define my model again, create the mom file, generate the class, and reimport all data, I guess

Comment: You could back your entity with a custom class that essentially only adds the readonly property. This might induce a new version of  the data model and thus needs a data migration which should be doable as both versions of the data model only differ in the addition of a custom class. Automatic migration should be able to take care of that as long as you have the old and the new version of the dat amodel avilable.

Comment: This is interesting as well, to be considered for future apps. This time I worked it out, and probably we can affirm that it is not possible to build such a predicate, isn't it? Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Since NSPredicates allow you to use everything which matches Key-Value Coding approach you can call on NSStrings methods like: intValue or floatValue

```
NSString * conditionToBeAdded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" && (propertyName.floatValue >= %f )  && (propertyName.floatValue <= %f)", myMinFloat, myMaxFloat];
stringForPredicate = [stringForPredicate stringByAppendingString:conditionToBeAdded];  
NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringForPredicate];
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This syntax works, but the results are still incorrect. A predicate like: attribute01.intValue < 120 does not return strings that contain "50"

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change that string to a number and fix it properly.  String searching is **SLOW** and should be avoided.  Putting numbers into strings is a big performance hit with no gain.

As for your actual predicate, you can do a < or > comparison on strings.  I suspect all of those quotation marks you have in the predicate are throwing things off.  Quotation marks are not needed in predicates unless you are setting a constant which in this case you are not.  Remove them and try it again.