# issue in NSPredicate for NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

In my application I am using CoreData.Amount values are stored in coreData as NSString. In my Interface Builder i have two textfields.When i enter any amount on my textfields This amounts will accept as Minimum Value and maximum Value.I want to get all amounts between minimum and maximum amounts i have entered.

What will be the solution.I just goes through this way [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879286/nspredicate-how-to-treat-strings-as-numbers) It Not be worked on my project because i want to convert string to integer on my NSPredicate method.

My code is

```
 NSPredicate *p1= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(amount.intValue => %@) && (amount.intValue <=%@)", text1.intValue,text2.intValue]];
```

Note that amount is stored as NSString in coredata

Comment: did you tried `(amount.intValue => %d)` this?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data from DB with this predicate? or filtering fetched data from DB?

Comment: Why storing amount as `NSString`? Can you change it to `NSNumber`

Comment: Do you get any error, or is the result just empty?

Comment: amount is taken from core data.why we call like this amount.text1

Comment: I get incorrect Result.Their is no error or crash

Comment: I changed NSString format to NSNumber(double) on coredata. What changes want to be done on nspredicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NSPredicate *p1= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(amount.intValue => %@) && (amount.intValue <=%@)", text1.intValue,text2.intValue]];

You shouldn't be comparing numbers and strings. Compare one or the other. In this case, you want to compare numbers. You should change your source data stored in the model to be a number.

`=>` should be `>=`

`%d` is an integer parameter format, and `text1.intValue` returns an integer. Using `%@` expects an on jest and won't do what you want.

Log the contents of the predicate so you can see what it contains. But mainly, change the type of the data in the model.

Comment: "=> should be >=" [Both syntaxes are supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215832). But for consistency's sake, I agree.

Comment: I changed NSString format to NSNumber(double) on coredata. What changes want to be done on nspredicate

Comment: Try: `NSPredicate *p1= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(amount >= %d) && (amount <= %d)", text1.intValue, text2.intValue]];`

Answer (score 1):

As you store amount as NSString, you need to pass it as NSNumber when doing the evaluation.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.intValue <= $max.intValue AND SELF.intValue >= $min.intValue"];
```

Now you can evaluate the amount to see if it is in range

```
if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:amount.intValue] substitutionVariables:@{@"max":[NSNumber numberWithInt:text1.intValue], @"min":[NSNumber numberWithInt:text2.intValue]}])
{
    //Got the correct amount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currect Answer is

```
NSPredicate *p1= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(amount >= %d) && (amount <= %d)", text1.intValue, text2.intValue]];
```